# PHP email form that responds to current html rather than opening a 'thank you' page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've set up an email form on my website and right now it sends users to a thank you page using `header('Location:emailConfirmation.html');`. I want to try something else and replace the html of the form with a message using javascript. i.e. call a function like this

```
function emailConfirmed()
{
    $('#email').load('emailConfirmation.html');
}
```

Something less intrusive, that doesn't leave the main page. Is something like this possible?

Here's my current form code.

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="scripts/contact-form-handler.php">
    <p>
        <label for='name'>Your Name:</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='email'>Email Address:</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='message'>Message:</label> <br>
        <textarea name="message" maxlength="600" cols="25" rows="6" style="margin: 2px; width: 300px; height: 110px;resize:none;"></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactform");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address");
</script>
```

Comment: use AJAX, on submission call a php page and then replace the form with a thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) to `send mail` like,

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
           url:$('form[name="contactform"]').attr('action'),
           data:$('form[name="contactform"]').serialize(),
           type:'POST',
           success:function(){
              $('#email').load('emailConfirmation.html');
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Add an `id` to your `submit button` like,

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"><br>
```

Also to get the the `message` in `#email` add a `div` after your `form` like,

```
<form ...>
   ....
</form>
<div id="email"></div><!-- Element to get the message afte ajax success callback -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If the main part of the page is within a div (say, "main") then you can do something like this:

```
$('#main').html("Thank you.<br/><br/>Your form has been sent.");
```

If you'd like to include more content, you can load it from an external file or even just hard-code it into the JavaScript.

Comment: This approach won't load a new page, it'll just replace the content with whatever you pass to the html() method.

Answer (score 0):

you want to load html file. done using this code i hope this is working for you.

```
$( "#email" ).load( "emailConfirmation.html", function() {
         alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

please try and [More Detail](http://api.jquery.com/load/)